# Factorization of large number has stopped working in a for loop

Tags: c, arrays

Whenever I start my program, the windows pop-up appears and says "test.exe has stopped working." I am getting no errors from my compiler. Here is my code. I have mentioned where the error occurs but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long long factor[999], halfof;
    int i;

    long long num = 600851475143;

    halfof = num / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++){
        factor[i] = 0;
    }


    //GETTING ERROR IN THIS "FOR LOOP"
    for (i = 2; i <= halfof; i++){
        if (num % i == 0){
            factor[i] = i;
        }
    }




for (i = 0; i < 999; i++){
        printf("%ld", factor[i]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `factor` defined?

Comment: long long factor[999], halfof; You can check the pastebin if you need to see all the code

Comment: num = 600,851,475,143
halfof = 300,425,737,071.5
INT_MAX = 4,294,967,295

`int i` is not able to loop until `halfof` value, and thus the error. Try changing `int i` to `long long i` as well

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info; `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Learn to **use the debugger** [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From below code segment in your code:

```
long long factor[999], halfof;
long long num = 600851475143;
halfof = num / 2;
```

This gives `halfof`  way more than `999` , which are maximum elements of `factor`.

Here : `factor[i] = i;` you are doing out of bound array access, which may lead to [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (If you are lucky).

Answer (score 2):

Your code for factorizing the number is wrong - you shouldn't be using `i` to track the index of `factor` at all. You'll need to separately track the last used factor assigned with its own index (I've added a variable for this)
As per other comments, you also need to make `i` a `long long` so that it can track through `num`. You might also consider increasing the number of elements in `factor` to handle numbers with large numbers of factors (these numbers can be surprisingly small).

To find all unique factors of `num`:

```
long long i;
int factorIndex = 0;
for (i = 2; i <= halfof; i++){
   if (num % i == 0){
      factor[factorIndex++] = i;
   }
}

for (i = 0; i < factorIndex ; i++){
    printf("%ld ", factor[i]);
}
```

[Example here](https://ideone.com/yVkC4T#stdin)

**Notes**

- that this finds all factors of a number (other than 1, and the number itself). Factorizing all **prime factors** is a different algorithm altogether.
- 999 may be insufficient for many 'promiscuous' [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number) with large numbers of factors. You may need to increase your array bounds.
- You can check against the [factors here](http://statsfiddle.info/Primes/AllFactors/600851475143) (Disclaimer, my site).

Comment: Example of a highly composite number: `2205403200`, which is considerably smaller than your `600851475143` has 1680 factors (1678 if you exclude 1 and itself), which will be too large for your '999' factor array

Answer (score 1):

Problems

1. Array indexing

   In `factor[i] = i` you are indexing the array from 2.
   You leave index 0, 1 blank
2. Looping more than array size

   `600851475143/2 > 999`

Comment: @Vagish yes it is.

Comment: @Vagish - Definitely YES.